# Apache - 406 Not Acceptable PHP Problem

Tags: php, flash, apache

I'm debugging a flash website that do a request to an php file named upload.php to upload some images to the server.

The problem i'm having that debugging it with Firebug the request to that page is throwing a 406 Not Acceptable status code and is not saving the images.

**Post Data:**

[alt text http://pixelstg.com/rum_post_info.JPG](http://pixelstg.com/rum_post_info.JPG)

This website runs well on the staging server but in production server this process of the image upload fails. I only can assume that a change to apache configuration / php must be done, but i have no idea what to do.

**upload.php code:**

[alt text http://pixelstg.com/rum_upload_code.JPG](http://pixelstg.com/rum_upload_code.JPG)

Any help or guidance will be welcome, thanks in advance for the help.

att
Sherlack

Comment: Can you show a typical image that will fail? How large is it?

Comment: the images size are about 50kb - 100kb in jpg format.

Comment: I'm trying the solutions below to try them out. Will keep in touch. 

thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Suhosin PHP hardening module. Some of the variable value length limits were being exceeded. The file that was edited was /etc/php.d/suhosin.ini and it logs to /var/log/.

After the file was edited by my hosting administrator the problem was resolved.

Thanks all for your support!

Answer (score 3):

A `406 Not Acceptable` error means the server wants to send a response which type is not listed in the `accept` headers sent by the client (in this case, Flash); it is unrelated to your files failing to upload.

Your code looks fine, so this might be an issue with your PHP configuration. Make sure `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` is configured adequately in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers (post_max_size it probably is, hence my question for the image size), [**this blog entry**](http://bradleyboy.com/blog/archives/2006/12/flash_upload_ht.php) outlines a more uncommon reason for a 406 in conjuction with a Flash file upload, apparently caused by `mod_security`.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with your post_max_size.

In php.ini change the following to a number that matches your need:

```
memory_limit = 0M
post_max_size = 0M
upload_max_filesize = 0M
```

If this does not work then you will need to do a similar change in your .htaccess file in Apache.

Comment: I check these values and they configure as follow: 

memory_limit = 32M,
post_max_size = 8M,
upload_max_filesize = 8M, 


But still doesnt work and the upload returns the 406 status code.

Comment: I'm gonna try to do these settings now in .htaccess to see if it works.

Comment: Ok, i tried setting up memory_limit , post_max_size,upload_max_filesize in the htaccess file but didnt work.

Comment: You have to do it in your PHP.ini file too. Plus is your post and upload_max_size over 8mb. Change your PHP.ini file with a higher value

Comment: Copy the PHP.ini and Apache config values from your test server (test it) - if it works then change each value (one at a time) to what they need to be in production to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just needed to change headers(as Johannes Gorset said) to:

```
"Accept":"text/html"
```

Disabling mod_security was not an option.

I was sending a multi-part/form and receiving this annoying error. Changing "Accept header" solved my issue.