# 406 and 404 error - issue only with Firefox?

Tags: php, javascript, html, http, firefox

website giving 404 and 406 error on Firefox 9.01.

While other browsers like IE8, Opera 11.52,Safari 5.0.4 and Chrome 16.0.912.63 don't have this issue and every page opens normally.

What could be the problem ?

Some information about page:
page type:PHP
basic jquery UI code is present
Google adsense enabled.

> Not Acceptable
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource / could not be found on this
>       server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an
>       ErrorDocument to handle the request.

For a quick reference I have added tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: What specifficly doesn't work? I'm not havin any problems. Also this coud be in you cache, so Ctrl+F5, maybe it'll help :)

Comment: Only on article.php some javascripts doesn't exist. (eg. http://webtunings.com/js/article/18.js)

Comment: i cleared all cache,cookies, still i have issue with FF 9.01

Comment: @Dagon i have also 9.0.1 but it's not working.

Comment: @Kristian that should not be a problem, what do u say?

Comment: @Kristian, that's a good news that it's working in ur FF 9.0.1 but mine is not working. I have added snapshot in question.

Comment: Maybe that will help if tour'e using apache: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/apache-mod-security-update-how-to-fix-error-406-or-not-acceptable-issue-259

Comment: thanks i will look into that link, but my markup is valid and clean, still 406 problem :(

Comment: Do you have access to server logs?

Comment: i have server logs but that doesn't have anything for today's log.

Comment: @Kristian it not helps, but thank's for Ctrl+F5 tips lol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get yourself charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) or another webproxy like it and watch the request sent by your Firefox and another Browser of your choice there might be a bad cookie or some rewrite working behind the scenes to destroy your experience.

If you can't figure it out screenshots of the charles log from your firefox request would probably help shed some light here.

Comment: can i get 406 with invalid data sent by browser? or it's from server side?

Comment: Yes you can get this for example if your browser declares not to accept text/html while requesting an html page or something like that. Maybe your headers are misconfigured...

Comment: Server-side. Quote: "A 406 Not Acceptable error means the server wants to send a response which type is not listed in the accept headers sent by the client." from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291662/apache-406-not-acceptable-php-problem

Comment: You might also want to take a look inside the server's error logs if you got access to those. There miht be some valuable information about what is going on.

Comment: can u guys please see into headers? i have added snapshot of httpFox. I am not very much comfortable with HTTP headers .

Answer (score 1):

The [406 response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7) indicates a problem at the HTTP level. The code on the page might still be relevant if it somehow causes a redirect. But this seems to be an odd problem where your Firefox sends some strange HTTP headers and the server regards them as a request that cannot be satisfied. However, I tried sending the server requests with absurd headers like Accept-Encoding: foo and Accept: foo/bar and it did not seem to care. But it might still be a good idea to check out what Firefox sends (see bardiir’s suggestions, or install the Tamper Data add-on).